How to solve this system of inequalities?
I have four variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, each value can only be 1 or 0. And I have a system of inequalities:
$4x_1+2x_2+x_3 \neq 0$
$4x_1+2x_2+x_3 \neq 2$
$4x_1+2x_2+x_3 \neq 1$
$4x_1+2x_2+x_4 \neq 1$
$4x_1+2x_2+x_4 \neq 3$
$4x_1+2x_2+x_4 \neq 4$
I want to get only one possible solution, like $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = 1$. But how can I get a solution? Any available algorithms are appreciated. (Actually I have much more variables and inequalities in a real problem, but every inequality looks like $4x_i + 2x_j + x_k \neq  p, p \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}, i < j < k$.)

With your example, there are only $2^4=16$ possible combinations, so try them all, and see which ones satisfy all of your inequalities.
For the general case, this is a nice exercise, and I will leave it to you to work out the details.  You might try looking for a reduction.

Definitely a kick-self moment when you spot the trick.
